# Question about the proof about topological compactifications of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness, compactification, alexandroff-compactification

I have a question regarding the proof about compactifications of $\mathbb{R}$.
I am reading **Van Douwen**´s paper C**haracterizations of $\beta \mathbb{Q}$ and $\beta \mathbb{R}$**, where he defines:

> We call a compactification $\gamma X$ of a space $X$ topological if
> every autohomeomorphism $h$ of $X$ has a continuous extension $\gamma h: \gamma X \rightarrow \gamma X$.

and then he proves that

> for the halfline $\mathbb{H}$, $\alpha \mathbb{H}$ and $\beta \mathbb{H}$ are the only topological compactifications of
> $\mathbb{H}$.

He then states as an immediate consequence that

> $\alpha \mathbb{R}$, $\beta \mathbb{R}$ and the two-point
> compactification are the only three topological compactifications of
> $\mathbb{R}$.

**My question is**: Why is this immediatelly seen? I would like to show this a bit more precisely.

I tried to say this:

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the map $f: x \rightarrow - x$ induces an autohomeomorphism of $\beta \mathbb{R}$ which implies that $\beta[0,\infty)$ is identical with $\beta(-\infty,0]$.

But I am not sure how to conclude exactly the result. Will appreciate any help.

---

P.S. $\alpha X$ denotes the Alexandroff one-point compactification and $\beta X$ denotes the Stone-Čech compactification.

P.P.S. I am sorry I couldn´t find the paper link online.

Comment: There are some weirdly placed inequality signs here. What do $\gamma\gt h$ and $\beta\gt\Bbb H$ mean?

Comment: @FShrike It was a typo, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You have" $\alpha\Bbb{R}, \alpha\Bbb{R}$" in your quote of the "immediate consequence". Is that right?

Comment: @RobArthan It was a typo, sorry. Now it should be correct